# List used space for blobs, files, tables, queues using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

How can I print separately the value how much space does blobs, files, tables, queues take using PowerShell?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you show us that code and explain why it is not giving you the wanted results?

Comment: @Theo thanks for the answer, but I don’t even know which side to go on, I can’t find the cmdlets (

Answer (score 2):

I haven't reproduced or tested your requirement end-to-end but I believe it can be accomplished by [Get-AzMetric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-2.6.0) cmdlet.

In this case, manually we can fetch the capacity details by going to 'Metrics' tile of your storage account in Azure Portal. Get-AzMetric cmdlet is PowerShell way of the same.

Below command should be the one you would have to use a lot in your complete automation to fetch account, blob, file, queue, table capacities.

```
(Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "{resource_id}" -MetricName "{metric_name}").Data
```

Note that there are many useful parameters that comes with the cmdlet Get-AzMetric which you may leverage to get the filtered output as required.

In the above command you would have to replace `{resource_id}` with below one's for storage account, blob, file, queue, table respectively.

Resource ID's:

```
/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageaccount_name}/
/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageaccount_name}/blobServices/default
/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageaccount_name}/fileServices/default
/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageaccount_name}/queueServices/default
/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageaccount_name}/tableServices/default
```

In the above command you would have to replace `{metric_name}` with below one's for storage account, blob, file, queue, table respectively.

Metric names:

```
UsedCapacity
BlobCapacity
FileCapacity
QueueCapacity
TableCapacity
```

If you want to fetch some other metric data using the same approach then you can get the metric name by below command or by checking in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftstoragestorageaccountsblobservices) document.

```
(Get-AzMetricDefinition -ResourceId "{resource_id}").name.value
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

**UPDATE**:

Please find below screenshot as illustration for using Get-AzMetricDefinition.
[image]

**UPDATE2**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. You are cool. It worked for storage account. But did not work for Blob, File, Queue, Table. When i use the command (Get-AzMetricDefinition -ResourceId $id).Name where $id = '/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageaccount_name}/tableervices/{table_name}' I have error . Could you please help me? Where I can find name for table? Thanks.

Comment: Error `Get-AzMetricDefinition : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: 
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.MetricDefinitionsOperations.<ListWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---`

Comment: Ah! Firstly, there was a typo for table related resource id in the answer. Just now I have corrected it. Secondly, I just did a quick check using Get-AzMetricDefinition command on few of my storage services and I couldn't reproduct the badrequest error so I would suggest you to make sure you update the Az PowerShell module to latest version and just double check if you are giving correct details w.r.t subscription id, resource group name, etc. Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: For illustration of using Get-AzMetricDefinition cmdlet you may refer the screenshot that is added under UPDATE section of the answer. Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: thank you very much after your corrections no error. But
`$test.Data


TimeStamp : 9/23/2019 6:22:00 PM
Average   : 
Minimum   : 
Maximum   : 
Total     : 
Count     : 

`
but there is no data in the output(((( Help me

Comment: ``` Name       : 
                 LocalizedValue : Blob Capacity
              Value          : BlobCapacity
             
Type       : Microsoft.Insights/metrics
Unit       : Bytes
Data       : 
Timeseries : {}
```

Comment: Got you! So now I have jumped to test this as it was failing for you! :) And then got to know that we have to use '/default' at the end of resource id for blob, file, table, queue. I have updated the above answer accordingly and added few screenshots for illustration under UPDATE2. Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a genius. You could give me your contacts. I would like to keep in touch with you for learning Azure

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Glad to know that I was able to help resolve your issue. My email ID is krishna.gtbm@yahoo.com but I would recommend you to ask questions in public forums like MSDN, StackOverflow only so that it will help broader audience who look for answers to similar issues.